# when i copy all files from local file system /var/log/httpd to hadoop distributed file system using command

Tags: hadoop

Hi will you please help me to solve this this error?

```
[hadoop@bigdata hadoop]$  bin/hdfs dfs -put /var/log/httpd  logs
```

15/05/10 10:51:06 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform.using builtin-java classes where applicable
put: Error accessing file:/var/log/httpd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [hadoop@bigdata hadoop]$ bin/hdfs dfs -put /var/log/httpd logs

1. Create directory in HDFS:

`hdfs dfs -mkdir /logs`

2. Copy files into HDFS:

`hdfs dfs -put /var/log/httpd/*.* /logs/`

**NOTE:** If you cant copy into HDFS, it might be permission issue on folder /var/log/httpd

3. If you get permission denied error, try this:

`sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/httpdlogs`

`sudo chown hadoop:hadoop -R /usr/local/httpdlogs`

`sudo cp /var/log/httpd/*.* /usr/local/httpdlogs/`

`hdfs dfs -put /usr/local/httpdlogs/*.* /logs/`

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Thanks for answer it's a permission issue and resolved successfully. Thanks again.